# iPhone tabbar strange problem

Tags: iphone, tabbar

look what's happened. One time it works nice but another time happen this:

[image]

Why? How can I solve?

EDIT: [image]

Comment: Please explain, in detail, the problem that you're seeing.

Comment: Its difficult to get what the problem just after having look at the image,u need to describe with some text notations.

Comment: Look the tabbar. It's white. I don't set anything.. One time is black and is correct and one time is like the image, wrong. Why?

Comment: @Joaquin - Could you provide us with a little more information, like how you presented the tab bar or what exactly happened before it went white?  A little example code would help, too.

Comment: It's a simple tabbar application with 3 tabs. It's strange because the problem happen only in the simulator, but not in the device. I attach now a new screenshot with the problem at the moment when I run application, look.

Comment: @Joaquin - How do you create the tab bar (Interface Builder, etc.)?  What does your view hierarchy look like?  We can't diagnose something just from images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only happens in the simulator, don't worry about it. The simulator isn't always accurate, and performance on a device is the final measure.